# How to get values on specific API column

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I'm creating an e-commerce site and I'm trying to fetch a certain Cart with a foreign key or the second column of my table which is the `userID` using Axios GET request.
this is my table structure

```
cartID | userID | | productName
1          1            chair
2          3            ....
3          3            ....
```

how do I display the data which has the only `userID` of `3`?

because i can't do it this way
`axios.get("https://localhost:3000/api/carts/cartID/userID/3")`

this is how i get the data

```
const [myCart, setMyCart] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://localhost:3000/api/carts/")
      .then((res) => {
        setMyCart(res.data)
        console.log(res.data)
      })
  }, []);
```

this is how I display the data

```
{myCart.map((item, index) => {
              return(
              <tr key={index.id}>
                  <td >{index + 1}</td>
                  <td>{item.name}</td>
              </tr>
  )}
)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a condition like this:

```
{
  myCart.map((item, index) => {
    if (item.id === 3) {
      return (
        <tr key={index.id}>
          <td>{index + 1}</td>
          <td>{item.name}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    }

    return null;
  });
}
```

Comment: woah, it was just that simple! thanks. btw i changed the  `if (index.id === 3) {`  to `if (userID.id === 3) { `

Comment: Yes. Just update with `item.id` from `myCart`

Comment: i mean `if (index.id === 3) `  to  `if (item.userID === 3) { ` , sorry i can't edit my comment above.